# Intuition for complex eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, intuition, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The eigenvalues of a rotation matrix are complex numbers. I understand that they cannot be real numbers because when you rotate something no direction stays the same.

**My question**
What is the intuition that the eigenvalues are complex? Why do they exist at all for rotation matrices? I mean it is not so that every time a calculation is not possible the result is complex (dividing by 0 is not possible at all - the result is not real, but it is not complex either!). The complex numbers seem to cover some middle ground here, but I don't understand how and why they come into play - there don't seem to be any square roots taken from negative numbers...)

Comment: Did you mean "The eigenvalues of a rotation matrix..."? In any event, if you'll look at the two-by-two case, you'll note that the eigenvalues of a rotation matrix are always complex unless the rotation angle is an integer multiple of $\pi$, so there is no reason to expect that higher-dimensional rotation matrices would behave differently.

Comment: @J.M.: Thank you - fixed it!

Comment: With regards to the eigenvectors: if the matrix is real, and the eigenvalue is complex, you should expect the corresponding eigenvector to have complex components.

Comment: Complex numbers are not just real numbers (real axis) and square roots of negative real numbers (imaginary axis). Most complex eigenvalues of a matrix will be a+bi where a and b are both nonzero. The intuition you need is the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra: any nonconstant polynomial with complex (e.g., real) coefficients has a complex root.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Heuristically, I suppose we could see this being because the standard action of the complex numbers on $V = \mathbb R^{2n}$ is by rotation. That is, $(e_1, \ldots, e_{2n})$ is a basis for $V$, then we define multiplication by $i$ as

$ i e_{2k-1} = e_{2k}, \quad i e_{2k} = - e_{2k-1},$ for $k = 1, \ldots, n$,

so multiplying a vector $v$ by a complex number $\lambda$ will correspond to a scaling by a real and a rotation.

Now, if we have a rotation $A$ on the space $V$ and we want to find a line $l$ "invariant" under $A$, then we can try to look for a complex number $\lambda$ such that rotation of $l$ under $A$ is equivalent to the action of $\lambda$ on $l$. Thus, we can try and look for complex eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$.

This line of "reasoning" completely breaks down in the odd-dimensional case, because we can't define a complex structure on odd-dimensional spaces, but it might give a hint into why we'd look for complex eigenvalues at all. Then it becomes a matter of algebra to figure out that it actually works, and that it does so in a vector space of any finite dimension.

Finally, for the existence, as Alex already pointed out, we look for eigenvalues by finding roots of polynomials. All polynomials admit a root over the complex numbers, which translates into the existence of a complex eigenvalue.